# git / git-flow: after reintegrating upstream changes via merges, reorganize branch with a rebase

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-flow

I have a branch Z that was based on some upstream version X, had some features A, B, C developed in feature branches and then merged back and at some points had upstream changes X', X'' reintegrated back into Z.

```
X-----------X'-------X''
 \           \        \
  Z-------Z1--Z2---Z3--Z4------Z5
   \      / \      /    \      /
    A1--A2   B1--B2      C1--C2
```

I would like to port my branch Z with its features A, B, C to another branch Y (which is upstream, like X). To do this more easily, I would first like to untangle Z like this:

```
X--X'--X''
        \
         Z-------Z1------Z2------Z3
          \      /\      /\      /
           A1--A2  B1--B2  C1--C2
```

My first thought was to use `git rebase --onto X'' X Z3`, which worked but killed all merges, so the result looked more like

```
X''--A1--A2--B1--B2--C1--C2
```

My next attempt was `git rebase --preserve-merges --onto X'' X Z3`, which did ... nothing at all? Well, I guess I did tell it to preserve merges, but I wanted to keep my "feature-merges" and throw away the "reintegration-merges".

Any ideas on how to achieve this or did I do something wrong?

At the moment it looks like I have to recreate the branch manually by carefully cherry-picking and/or rebasing and re-merging my feature branches.

Another alternative would be to squash the feature branches together so I don't have to preserve merges.

Comment: Does the following post help: http://blog.adamspiers.org/2013/09/19/easier-upstreaming-with-git/

Comment: The commands introduced there are nice (although they inexplicably fail with errors on some commits), but don't solve the problem at hand.